# Does Hölder continuity imply smoothness for the CMC equation: $u:D^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $\Delta u = 2H\partial_xu\times\partial_yu$, $H$ constant?

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Context: I am currently reading through the freely available lecture notes from Tristan Riviere ([here](http://www.fim.math.ethz.ch/~riviere/papers/Minicours-Vancouver0709.pdf)) on the applicability of integration by compensation in the analysis of various geometrically motivated PDEs.

I have attempted to find something in the vast literature to the following effect: suppose $u:D^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $u\in W^{1,2}$, $\Delta u = f(u,\nabla u) = 2H\partial_xu\times\partial_yu$. Then

$$u\in C^{0,\alpha}(D') \rightarrow u\in C^\infty(D''),$$

where $D'' \subset\subset D' \subset\subset D$.

In other words, an interior estimate.  With the little regularity on hand, it appears to be very difficult.  I find this surprising because most of the time, proving the Hölder regularity of the solution is the 'most difficult' part.  I have the feeling that I am missing an obvious reference or a well-known folklore argument.

Showing the Hölder continuity of the solution relies on deriving a Morrey-type estimate with the help of the Wente lemma.  In the process of doing this, one also shows that

$$\sup_{\rho < 1/2, p\in B_{1/2}(0)} \rho^{-\alpha} \int_{B_\rho(p)} |\Delta u|$$

is bounded.  This implies that $f\in\mathcal{H}^1$.  I just include this extra detail in case this question fits into a general framework of optimal interior regularity for Poisson's equation on a disk when the right hand side is Hardy.  (This is the reason for the earlier form of my question.)

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why do you believe this to be true?

Comment: To be explicit, $u = (x_1)^p$ for an appropriate value of $p$ is perhaps the simplest counterexample.

Also, you seem to imply that assuming $f$ is in the Hardy space is a weaker assumption than $L^1$, but it is a stronger assumption (since, as you say, the Hardy space is smaller).

Comment: Yes, I know the Hardy space is a stronger assumption.  I meant to write 'must' not 'can'--- I will edit the question.  I also failed to write that $f$ is a function of $u$ and $\nabla u$ with critical quadratic growth in $\nabla u$.

Comment: I'm still confused. Surely, you don't meant that $f$, as a function of $u$ and $\nabla u$ is only in a Hardy space?

Comment: $f(u,\nabla u) = 2H\partial_xu \times \partial_yu$, where $H$ is a constant.  What I understand well is how to prove the Hölder continuity of the (weak) solution so long as we assume $u\in W^{1,2}$.  To go from Hölder continuity to smoothness (in this situation) is the step which I do not understand.  In the proof of the Hölder continuity, one also shows some growth of the laplacian of the solution (reminiscent of a Morrey-type estimate) which allows one to conclude that the right hand side is in $\mathcal{H}^1$.  I am sorry to have confused you both.

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your question with a more precise description of $f$, and you should be able to get good answers from people more expert at this than me.

Comment: @Deane Yang I have rewritten the question.  The reason for the earlier form was not to mislead, but only because I believed that this followed from some general folklore theorem.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Sorry for the quibbling, but what is $H$? If it is a function, what regularity are you assuming for it?

Comment: It is just a constant.  (I mentioned this in the title of the question, and the comment above.)  And don't be sorry, I do my fair share of quibbling also.

Comment: And have you tried bootstrapping? The idea is that if $u$ is Holder, then the right side of your equation is in $L^p$ for some $p$. Elliptic regularity then implies that $u$ is in $W^{p,2}$. This in turn in implies stronger regularity of the right side. Now just repeat the argument.

Comment: I have indeed.  I guess that one can see this question as how to really get the bootstrapping to work here.  I understand that one should in principle be able to interpolate between the Hölder and Sobolev norms, and then use this to show $u\in W^{1,p}$ for $p > 2$.  This would be enough to start bootstrapping.  To get the right hand side in $L^p$ for $p > 1$, one needs to approximate and then relax to a limit. The convergence of the approximation doesn't come out for me.Even using the variational characterisation of the PDE doesn't seem to help.So I figured maybe this was the wrong approach...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm too lazy to type-up the proof myself, so I'll send you to a reference.

[Chang, S.-Y. A., Wang, L. and Yang, P. C. (1999), "Regularity of harmonic maps". CPAM](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1692152) has the proof in Section 3. Once you get $C^{1,\gamma}$ you immediately get RHS is in $C^\gamma$ and the rest follow by standard elliptic regularity.

Note that the structure of the equation (RHS being of the form $d(u\cdot du)$) is only used for Wente's lemma. For the upgrade of regularity one uses a Caccioppoli type inequality.

(BTW, the Chang-Wang-Yang result bypasses the Hardy space estimates. For that the result can be found in the original paper of [Helein](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1101039), though I'd guess the material is also in his [book](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1913803) if you don't read French.)

Comment: Thanks Willie.  I will check out the reference.  But in this question I only have Hoelder continuity of the solution, not $C^{1,\alpha}$.  I am aware that once the RHS is $C^\alpha$ then the standard regularity argument works fine.  Thanks for the reference though, if one needs to work harder and obtain $C^{1,\alpha}$ then that's still useful.  On Helein: I have been through Helein's book.  He obtains the Hoelder continuity of the solution and then refers to the elliptic book by Ladyzhenskaya and Uraltseva.  I couldn't find the argument with the correct growth on the RHS in that book however.

Comment: The reference I gave **is** to obtain $C^{1,\alpha}$ from just Holder. I made that comment since in your question you ask for smooth, while the section title for section 3 of Chang, Wang, and Yang's paper is "$C^{1,\gamma}$ regularity", so I thought I'd remark that *that* is enough. 

Comment: (In fact that paper also contains a proof of Holder regularity from just $W^{1,2}$...)

Comment: You're right.  Thanks for the answer :).